# RegEx for text field for names - no numbers allowed and cannot be left as blank

Tags: regex, validation, textfield

I am working on validation using RegEx for a text field for names. I am using the RegEx below but it is not working:

```
^[a-zA-Z,'.\-\s]*$
```

and also this:

```
(?! $)[a-zA-Z ]
```

Please help, thanks!

Comment: What isn't working?  Are you matching too much or too little?  What do you want it to do?  Show some inputs and outputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work: `^[^\d]+$`. It means that it will look into the string and it will match it if the string is made up from at least one, non digit character.

Edit:

As per @nhahtdh's comment, the regex above will allow anything which is not a digit. You could use something like so: `^[A-Za-z.-]+(\s*[A-Za-z.-]+)*$`. This will allow only strings which have spaces between them. This will stop the user from providing a field full of white spaces but it will work should the user provided something like so: `Hey there. My name is - foo bar`. The one you have: `^[a-zA-Z,'.\-\s]*$` with a minor adjustment of `^[a-zA-Z,'.\-\s]+$` will allow the user to provide white space fields.

Comment: This will allow names such as `!@#($)%"<:}\,]/.` to pass, though.

Comment: @nhahtdh: Yes I know. According to the title of the question, no numbers must be allowed. I'll modify my answer just in case the OP is after names made up from letters.

Comment: I think it is a bit deceiving to put up such regex. It is common that people only test for what they want to match, but neglect testing for what they don't want to match.

Comment: @MaxSmith: Glad it worked. If this helped you please mark the response as the answer. This will show up on your statistics and encourage people to any further questions you might have ;).

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you want

```
^(?!\s+$)[a-zA-Z,'. -]+$
  -------
     |->checks if the whole string is blank.if so it won't match
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using this one for names, as names don't contain special characters in my case, its at least one character and any number of intermediate spaces

```
[a-zA-Z]+[ a-zA-Z]*
```